# Loading data from server and saving in application

Tags: android

I am creating an application having two tabs and each tab show columns of images such as say recent and popular.
I fetch the image urls from server through php and get it in a JsonObject in the android app.
When I shift tabs, how can I use the already downloaded JsonObject instead of reloading from server.
I tried to save in an application object

```
public class myapp extends Application{
    private JSONObject job;

    private static myapp myinst;
    public void setJson(JSONObject jo)
    {
        job=jo;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate();
        myinst=this;
    }
    public static myapp getInstance()
    {
        return myinst;
    }
    public JSONObject getJson()
    {
        return job;
    }
}
```

But on running it gives error that the class of the Fragment representing the tab cannot be cast to Activity.
Is there any other way to save this data locally and not fetch again .
kindly update why error is coming with my application class and second the best way to store this JsonObject locally.
Thanks.

Comment: use local database or sharedpreference..

Comment: You can try SQLite DB instead of storing data in memory

Comment: SharedPreference would be good way if you want to store little but if you want to store a lot then you might make use of SQLite DB. You need to decode the images from server URL and save it in you local database.

Comment: Can you suggest is it not proper storing in the application object to make the program faster and why the error is coming for application object.